# Return multiple array from perl subroutine

Tags: perl, subroutine

I am giving four arguments to a perl subroutine, using them the routine creates two separate arrays `@temp_V`and `@temp_t`. When I try to return them to my main program, I don't get two separate arrays any more. Instead values in `@temp_t` append with `@temp_V`, giving me a single array.

How to resolve this issue? Here is my code:

```
$Vmin=-5;
$Vmax=5;
$N_pulses=5;
$Freq=25e3;

my (@V, @t)=create_FORC($Vmin,$Vmax,$Freq,$N_pulses);

print "@V \n\n\n"; 
#print "@t \n"; 

sub create_FORC($Vmin,$Vmax,$Freq,$N_pulses)
{
my $Vmin=shift;
my $Vmax=shift;
my $Freq=shift;
my $N_pulses=shift;

my $rtime=1/(4*$Freq);
#print "$rtime \n";

undef @temp_V;
undef @temp_t;

push(my @temp_V,0);
push(my @temp_t,0);

push(@temp_V,$Vmin);

      for (my $pulse=0;$pulse<$N_pulses;$pulse++)
      {
      $V_peak=($Vmax-$Vmin)/$N_pulses*($pulse+1)+$Vmin;
      $del_t=($V_peak-$Vmin)*$rtime;  
          push(@temp_V,$V_peak); 
          push(@temp_V,$Vmin);  
          push(@temp_t,$del_t);
      } 
 push(@temp_V,0);

 print "@temp_V \n";
 print "@temp_t \n";

return (@temp_V, @temp_t); 

}
```

Comment: _Always_ `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: Tip: **Always** use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Tip: You will likely never have a reason `undef @array;`

Comment: Tip: `push(my @temp_V,0);` is a weird way of writing `my @temp_V = 0;`

Comment: Tip: `for (my $pulse=0;$pulse<$N_pulses;$pulse++)` is a complex way of writing `for my $pulse (0..$N_pulses-1)`

Comment: Tip: `for my $pulse (0..$N_pulses-1) { ... ($pulse+1) ... }` can be simplified to `for my $pulse (1..$N_pulses) { ... $pulse ... }`

Answer (score 7):

You can't. When you return something from a sub, Perl returns a list. There is no information about how many elements where in the array before it comes out of the sub.

Lists are flat in Perl. They cannot be nested.

```
(1, 2, (3, 4), ((), 5, (6)), 7)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
((1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7))
```

If you want to return two distinct arrays, you need to return references to them.

```
sub foo {
    my @bar = qw/a b c/;
    my @qrr = qw/1 2 3/;

    return \@bar, \@qrr;
}

my ($letters, $numbers) = foo();
```

You can then dereference those into array variables, or access them directly.

See [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for more information on references.

Answer (score 6):

Return references to the arrays:

```
return \@temp_v, \@temp_t
```

You need to dereference them when assigning to real arrays:

```
my ($V_ref, $t_ref)=create_FORC($Vmin,$Vmax,$Freq,$N_pulses);
```

And then use `@$V_ref` instead of `@V` (and similarly for `@$t_ref` and `@t`).

You can't assing to two arrays at the same time, as the list on the right hand side of the assignment gets flattened and the first array eats all the values for itself.

Comment: Yes, here we go :)

Answer (score 2):

Arrays can't be passed to subs, only a number of scalars.

Arrays can't be returned by subs, only a number of scalars.

When you do

```
return ( @temp_V, @temp_t );
```

you are returning the contents of both arrays, as if you had done

```
return ( $temp_V[0], $temp_V[1], ..., $temp_t[0], $temp_t[1], ... );
```

Perl has no idea how many items to assign to the caller's `@V` and how many to assign to the caller's `@t`, so it assigns everything to `@V`.

The solution is to return references to the arrays (since references are scalars).

```
return ( \@temp_V, \@temp_t );
```

The caller then becomes

```
my ($V, $t) = create_FORC($Vmin, $Vmax, $Freq, $N_pulses);

print "@$V\n\n@$t\n";
```